# Process elements from an SQS queue sequentially using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I need to process the elements of an SQS Queue sequentially using an AWS Lambda. I need to process the elements sequentially as I don't want to impact the DB when processing multiple elements in parallel. Note that this process is not time-sensitive.

I have noticed that AWS Lambda reads up to 5 batches when messages are available, then invokes 5 Lambdas in parallel, which I want to avoid. Lambda may increase that number to up to 1000 batches. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: When you say "sequentially", do you simply mean "one-at-a-time", or do you also require them to be in the original order?

Comment: You can only do this with FIFO SQS. You can't control 5  lambdas in parallel.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein one-at-a-time, order is not important in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify the `--batch-size` parameter to `1`.
Other things to look at to achieve the desired outcome.

- Make sure you're using FIFO SQS queue
- Fetch 1 message at the time using `batch-size`
- Configure a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) for the SQS itself, so the messages that can't be processed after a several attempts are sent to DLQ SQS

Check the doco for details on each parameter supported by event source mapping
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-event-source-mapping.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your requirement is to:

- Process a single message at any time
- No parallel processing
- Order is not important
- Time is not important

This can be achieved by **setting a concurrency limit on the AWS function**, which limits the number of parallel executions.

From [Set Concurrency Limits on Individual AWS Lambda Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/set-concurrency-limits-on-individual-aws-lambda-functions/):

> This feature allows you to throttle a given function if it reaches a maximum number of concurrent executions allowed, which you can choose to set. This is useful when you want to limit traffic rates to downstream resources called by Lambda (e.g. databases).

Since order is not important, you can use a Standard Queue (instead of a FIFO queue).

Comment: It's important to understand how the Lambda poller works for this. With concurrency set to 1 you will likely end up with some throttled requests. How those throttles are handled depends on the message timeout and the Lambda timeout. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zysQqxgj0I talks about how that works near the 25 minute mark.